# PHP BackedEnum interface fails the instanceof operator

Tags: php, enums

Given:

```
enum TestEnum: string
{
  case CASE_1 = "first case";
  case CASE_2 = "Second case";
}
```

This is supposed to return `true`:

```
TestEnum::class instanceof \BackedEnum
```

But I get `false`

I tried the following from this [post](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.backedenum.php#126826) (it fails to run in Laravel Tinker REPL, but runs as a script?):

```
interface TestEnumInterface extends \BackedEnum
{
    public function foo(): string;
}

enum TestEnum: string implements TestEnumInterface
{
    case CASE_1 = 'case 1';
    case CASE_2 = 'case 2';

    public function foo(): string
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}



TestEnum::class instanceof \BackedEnum //false
TestEnum::class instanceof \TestEnumInterface //false
```

What am I missing?
Running PHP v8.1.13

Thanks

---

UPDATE:
Indeed, as per SomeOne1 reply, the following returns true:

```
TestEnum::CASE_1 instanceof \BackedEnum
```

Then I'll try to be more specific.
I have to test a variable `$list` which could be a number of different enums (like `$list = TestEnum::class` or `$list = AnotherEnum::class`), or a Laravel collection, or an array.

```
  //if ($list instanceof \BackedEnum) {
  if (isset($isEnum)) { // I want to get rid of this
    // do stuff
  }
  else if ($list instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection || $list instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection) {
    // do stuff differently
  }
  else if (is_array($list)) {
    // do stuff differently
  }
  else {
    var_dump($list);
    dd('invalid list');
  }
```

Then how can I test if this variable is of enum type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
if (is_string($list) && enum_exists($list)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

tests:

```
$list = TestEnum::class; //true
$list = [0, 1]; //false
$list = "ciao"; //false
$list = collect([0, 1]); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

TestEnum::class is not an instanceof an object, it is an 'instanceof' a string.
TestEnum::CASE_1 is instanceof of TestEnum or TestEnumInterface